# Запросы к myslq при реализации пагинации

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем. При реализации навигации по элементам базы данных изначально нужно знать общее количество этих элементов, а затем с помощью LIMIT указать границы выборки. Я правильно понимаю, что при этом всегда будет происходить **ДВА** запроса? Например :

```
1.кол-во элементов:
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl WHERE триста всяких условий

2.конкретно выборка 
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE те же триста условий LIMIT start,count_rows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаще всего именно в два запроса все происходит.

Есть еще вариант через [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: @Spawn, для  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS опять же нужно прописать все 300 условий.

Comment: По ссылке ходили? И Вы эти условия будете ручками что-ли писать, что такого в них страшного-то?

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() can be useful in situations when you want to restrict the number of rows that a query returns, but also determine the number of rows in the full result set without running the query again.

Comment: @Spawn, однако в запросе  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name нужно указывать LIMIT offset, length, значения которого вычисляются исходя из уже известного общего количества записей. Замкнутый круг.))
Эта штука хорошая, но не для этого случая.

Comment: зачем для LIMIT,OFFSET знать количество ? Вам надо посчитать сколько страниц.

Comment: @eicto, если и вы обратили внимание, значил я неправильно выразил свою мысль. В БД 2000 записей. У пользователя на экране виден список из 10 записей и  навигация 1,2,3,...20,21. Допустим он кликает на 20. Что это значит? Это значит, что 20*10-10 = 190. Ага, следовательно LIMIT 190,10. Из БД выбираются соответствующие записи и - на экран!

Comment: Мысль Вы выразили вполне ясно. Только непонятно, чем Вас не устраивает предложенный вариант.

В противовес, приведу пример с тем, с чем работаю каждый день сам. СУБД не поддерживает LIMIT и для постраничного вывода я сначала запрашиваю все ключи, а потом по ключами для каждой страницы достаю записи. Поверьте, по сравнению с этим, одинаковые запросы, отличающиеся только условием LIMIT, просто счастье.

Comment: @Spawn, да я уже и сам понял. Эти-то два запроса хоть и имеют одинаковые условия where, но работают с совершенно разными вещами. Первый - исключительно для вывода на экран самой навигации. Второй запрос - обрабатывает выбранный пользователем пункт в навигации. Ну конечно два запроса!

Answer (score 1):

наверное можно и так, но зачем тебе знать кол-во элементов? тебе надо знать только кол-во, которое надо вывести на экран и позицию на последнего на экране.
т.е. тебе достаточно только 2го запроса

Comment: @Gorets. Если у тебя неизвестное кол-во элементов, как ты будешь знать, сколько у тебя будет ссылок для навигации? Смешной у тебя ответ.

Comment: @Deus А вы в гугле когда что-нить ищете (ну там найдено примерно 10ккк страниц), поиск начинаете исключительно с 17-й страницы, а потом сразу 23-ю открываете? Смысла в номерах страниц нету никакого - это самый неудобный вариант навигации, с точки зрения юзабилити.  
<Назад|Далее> более чем достаточно, как вариант календарик для поиска по дням/месяцам если есть дата.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, лично  я когда не вижу чисел в навигации - теряюсь:  зловещая неопределенность пугает. К тому же, да, практически всегда я перескакиваю между страницами при навигации. И в третьих, что больше всего меня удивило, у вас в комментарии упоминаются числа 17 и 23 - это мои самые фартовые числа. Как вы так угадали?

Comment: @Deus, да, самые прикольные поджинаторы на две три страницы только цифр. Представляю пресловутый гугль говорит "найдено примерно 10 миллиардов ссылок" и паджинатор зафигачивает на миллиард чисел. Ни за что не потерялись бы, все четко детерминировано, никакой неопределенности...  
Я понимаю вашу иронию, но у вас вопрос такой несерьезный, что серьезно на него отвечать смысла нету. Ответ "да, надо два запроса" вас не устроил, а ответ, что нужен только один запрос вас развеселил.